# Cakephp containable order not working

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp containable to retrieve related models

```
$this->Order->find('first',
      array(
          'conditions'=>$conditions,
          'contain' => 
              array(
                 'OrderItem'=>array(
                     'Item'=>
                         array(
                            'order' => array('Item.item_number ASC')
                          )
                   ), 
             'Location','Campaign', "Customer")     
            )
       );
```

I'm using this to generate an invoice, and would like to have the items sorted by item_number.

But for some reason the sort isn't working.

Any ideas?

The SQL generated is very long. but you can see the issue from this snippet that the `order by` is in the wrong query  - - ie in the Item which is being select by id -- only one item. (And there is a seperate query for each item in the order. )

```
  SELECT `OrderItem`.`order_id`, `OrderItem`.`item_id`,
 `OrderItem`.`quantity`,  `OrderItem`.`id` FROM `order_items` AS `OrderItem` WHERE
 `OrderItem`.`order_id` = (3144)
```

And

```
  SELECT `Item`.`id`, `Item`.`campaign_id`, `Item`.`item_number`, `Item`.`description`,
  `Item`.`order_unit`, `Item`.`order_price`, `Item`.`maxQuantity`, `Item`.`sale_unit`,
  `Item`.`sale_price`, `Item`.`approx`, `Item`.`min_weight`, `Item`.`max_weight`,
  `Item`.`avail`, `Item`.`filename` FROM `items` AS `Item` WHERE `Item`.`id` = 122 
 ORDER    BY `Item`.`item_number` ASC
```

What I would like to see is the first query do a `inner join Items.id on OrderItem.item_id` and order that query by item_number, but I see that `containable` generates separate queries for each related model.

Comment: I ended up just creating a usort function to sort the OrderItems.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try Linkable instead:

https://github.com/Terr/linkable

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added:

`var $actsAs = array('Containable');`

to the Model, or

`$this->Order->Behaviors->attach('Containable');`

to the action. It isn't clear from your post if you have this already.

Also you should elaborate on `isn't working` - what isn't? Unexpected results? nothing at all?

Comment: I am creating an invoice, and would like the items to to be sorted by the item_number which is in the Items model. I get all the data, so containable works, but the sorting of the OrderItems doesn't work as expected. I just wrote a usort function to sort the order items... thanks for your input.....

Comment: @josephtikva It will return extra models if recursive is set, so you may think containable is working but in fact it is not.

Also, giving us the SQL generated would probably be helpful, as well as full code for the model.

Comment: @Ross I have that in the model.